# How to extend dataframe based on values in the same dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, apply, probability, tibble

I have the following tibble and I want to sample the arrival time for every passenger with a poisson distribution `rpois(n, lambda)`.

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  flight terminal passengers arrivaltime
  <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>
1 LX123  A                3         120
2 UA1    B                2         130
```

The final tibble should look like this and every row represents a single passenger with the arrival time being a sample from the poisson distribution with lambda being the arrival time of the flight in the first tibble.

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  flight terminal arrivaltime
  <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>
1 LX123  A              125
2 LX123  A              115
3 LX123  A              118
4 UA1    B              129
5 UA1    B              132
```

I already have the following code which calculates the rpois values and applies it to the tibble:

```
f = function(x, output){
  n = as.integer(x[[3]])
  lambda = as.integer(x[[4]])
  rpois(n, lambda)
} 
apply(tibble, MARGIN = 1, FUN = f)
```

My question is now how to complete my approach to create the second tibble. Since the dataset used is huge, fast computation is an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse` where we `uncount` based on the 'passengers' column, grouped by 'flight' apply the `rpois` with the number of rows (`n()`) and the `first` element of 'arrivaltime'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    uncount(passengers) %>%
    group_by(flight) %>%
    mutate(arrivaltime = rpois(n(), first(arrivaltime)))
```

---

Or another option is to use `map2` to loop over corresponding elements of 'passengers', 'arrivaltime' to apply the `rpois` and `unnest` the `list` column to expand the dataset rows

```
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(arrivaltime = map2(passengers, arrivaltime, rpois)) %>%
  unnest(c(arrivaltime))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  flight terminal passengers arrivaltime
#  <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>       <int>
#1 LX123  A                 3         127
#2 LX123  A                 3         110
#3 LX123  A                 3         131
#4 UA1    B                 2         109
#5 UA1    B                 2         133
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(flight = c("LX123", "UA1"), terminal = c("A", 
"B"), passengers = c(3, 2), arrivaltime = c(120, 130)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```